# Tem uma "margem" entre o titulo e o conteúdo

Tags: bug, status-recusado

Está tendo uma `div` (`<div id="dfp-tlb" class="everyonelovesstackoverflow"></div>`) em todas as perguntas. Isso está criando um espaço vazio entre o titulo e a mensagem:

[image: Exemplo]

Isso é um exemplo, mas parece que qualquer pergunta está assim.

---

O CSS é justamente:

```
#question .everyonelovesstackoverflow:empty {
    height: 90px;
    width: 728px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-bottom: 14px;
}
```

Comment: Pelo nome, parece que essa é uma `div` para algo promocional do SO

Answer (score 7):

Não estou vendo isso acontecer ao vivo, então já devem ter corrigido. Parece que alguém deixou escapar parte de um anúncio que só devia ser visível pra quem não está logado ou tem pouca rep:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Aqui ainda continua. Porém, acredito que é devido ao uso de AdBlock que o espaço fica vazio, ao invés do anuncio. Porém, antes não havia anúncios (e nem esse espaço) ali. :S

Comment: @Inkeliz eu ia responder isso mesmo, é o uso de algum tipo de adblock, é uma condição intencional [meta-tag:status-intencional], creio eu :)